# Laravel Spatie Permissions - There is no role named `student`

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-permission

I'm using the Laravel Permissions package by Spatie with Laravel Breeze. I created two registration forms for two types of users: "Student" and the other for "Instructor." When I create an account as **"Student,"**, it displays the following error message.

> There is no role named `student`.

**RegisteredUserController**

```
class RegisteredUserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the registration view for student.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function createStudent()
    {
        $role = Role::create(['name' => 'student']);
        return view('auth.student.student-space', compact('student'));
    }
    
    /**
     * Display the registration view for instructor.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function createInstructor()
    {
        $role = Role::create(['name' => 'instructor']);
        return view('auth.instructor.instructor-space', compact('role'));
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed|min:8',
        ]);

        Auth::login($user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]));
        
        $user->assignRole('student', 'instructor');
        $user->save();
        
        // Check if the "Student" has the correct role
        
        if ($user->hasRole('student')) {
            return redirect()->intended('/student/dashboard');
        }
        
        // Check if the "Instructor" has the correct role
        
        if ($user->hasRole('instructor')) {
            return redirect()->intended('/instructor/dashboard');
        }
        
        event(new Registered($user));
    }
}
```

**AuthenticatedSessionController**

```
   public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $request->authenticate();

        $request->session()->regenerate();
        
        if(auth()->check() && auth()->user()->hasRole('student')) {
            return redirect()->intended('/student/dashboard');
        }
        
        if(auth()->check() && auth()->user()->hasRole('instructor')) {
            return redirect()->intended('/instructor/dashboard');
        }
        
        // return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
```

**routes/auth.php**

```php
Route::get('/student-space',
    [RegisteredUserController::class, 'createStudent'])
    ->middleware('guest')->name('student-space');
Route::post('/student-space',
    [RegisteredUserController::class, 'store'])
    ->middleware('guest');
Route::get('/instructor-space',
    [RegisteredUserController::class, 'createInstructor'])
    ->middleware('guest')->name('instructor-space');
Route::post('/instructor-space',
    [RegisteredUserController::class, 'store'])
    ->middleware('guest');
```

Comment: `compact('student')` should also be `compact('role')`

Comment: is my code correct ?

Comment: it still display me this error message `There is no role named student`

Comment: Errr, no, just told you there's a mistake. Do you call those methods `createStudent()` and `createInstructor()` anywhere?

Comment: I call them in the **routes/auth.php** file

Comment: Does it work for the instructor role?

Comment: I update my question with **routes/auth.php** for the instructor role no I don't know why ??

Comment: When I try to register as **Instructor** it display this error message `There is no role named student.`

Comment: Do you hit those routes that create the roles anytime? Are there any roles in your db? I usually have a seeder that creates roles/permissions I need

Comment: I want to create roles based on what form are user using it if he want to register as Student he will user register form for Students and same thing for Instructors... and for the roles in database it should created when the users register

Comment: Create the roles so they already exist when running your app. Assign the roles as needed. `$user->assignRole('student', 'instructor');` assigns _both_ roles, what's the use of that? Good luck

Comment: I will do that and tell you the result

Comment: I update my code the **Instructor** dashboard it work well but when I tried to create and account for **Student** and waiting to redirect to dashboard for Students type it redirect me to **Instructor** dashboard and this is not what I want I will share a gist file with you to check where the problem is coming from. [Gist file](https://gist.github.com/devhoussam/1feef5e279b8acfc039d9d593740bdb6)